# How does one kill jobs submitted via bg in one subshell from another shell instance?

Tags: bash, kill, jobs

Suppose, as a dummy example, I execute a bash command in one terminal tab:

```
$: sleep 1000 &
```

Then, in another tab, I run the command that should "kill all background jobs":

```
$: jobs -p | xargs -a kill
```

Except nothing happens.  Or, better yet: how does one list all jobs started by my user via `<some-job> &` from any context?

Comment: `jobs -p | xargs -a kill` that command is totally bogus, and the only thing it will do is print the content of a file named `kill` (if such a file exists): `seq 1 10 > kill; jobs -p | xargs -a kill` => `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Comment: And no, not even the `kill $(jobs -p)` that you were probably meaning will not kill the background *jobs*, but only the *job leaders*. `sleep 1000 | sleep 1000 &`, then `kill -KILL $(jobs -p)`, `jobs -p` => LOL, still running. And you won't even be able to kill it again.

Comment: "How does one list all jobs started by my user via `<some-job> &` from any context?" You may just as well list all the processes with the same ID as yours, since any process could've been started in that manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jobs` command is a shell builtin, so is only intended for the current shell instantiation. In particular, the Bash manual describes `jobs` as:

> `-p`     List only the process ID **of the job's process group leader**.

(Emphasis mine.)

If you run `jobs -l`, you'll see that the sleep which you backgrounded in the other shell is not listed either.

The command to list *all* processes is `ps`. Its argument syntax can be a little baroque, so you're best off reviewing `man ps` for yourself. For myself, I usually use one of these:

```
ps aux
ps axjf
```

One just gives a list of all processes, the other arranges them in a dependency tree format. You might also try `pgrep` as a way of finding particular processes matched by name.

As a side note, if you're operating in a context where security is an issue, be aware that there are sneaky methods for hiding processes even from the root user, eg see https://github.com/gianlucaborello/libprocesshider.